# Error : Extender control 'AutoCompleteExtender1' is not a registered extender control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used autocompleteextender control of ajax in insertemplate & edittemplate of formview, it works fine in inserttemplate but when i try to edit content then it gives error as following:

> Extender control 'AutoCompleteExtender1' is not a registered extender
>   control. Extender controls must be registered using
>   RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().

I used following code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FV1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemInserting="FV1_ItemInserting"
DataSourceID="sqlds1" OnDataBound="FV1_DataBound" OnItemUpdating="FV1_ItemUpdating">
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl1">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="small-blocks">
            <div class="left" style="margin: 20px 10px 10px 0px;">
                <img src="images/icon-plane.png" width="25" height="21" alt="" /></div>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    list
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlist" runat="server" class="textfield-bk2" OnTextChanged="txtlist_TextChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="Searchlist" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                        EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtlist" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
                        runat="server" FirstRowSelected="true">
                    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl1">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="small-blocks">
            <div class="left" style="margin: 20px 10px 10px 0px;">
                <img src="images/icon-plane.png" width="25" height="21" alt="" /></div>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    list
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlist" runat="server" class="textfield-bk2" OnTextChanged="txtFrom_TextChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="Searchlist" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                        EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtlist" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
                        runat="server" FirstRowSelected="true">
                    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

What should i do to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: AJAX extenders cannot work correctly during callbacks because ScriptManager cannot determine what controls come from the server after callbacks.
I think that it might be better to avoid sending a callback. Utilize the UpdatePanel in your scenario.

Comment: I used updatepanel but getting same error.